# not vectorized: not suitable for gather D.32476_34 = *D.32475_33;

Tags: c++, optimization

I want to have my code autovectorized by compiler, but I can't seem to get it right.
In particular the message I am getting from it with `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=6`
option on is `125: not vectorized: not suitable for gather D.32476_34 = *D.32475_33;`.

Now my question is what whole this message means and what do those numbers stand for ?

Bellow, I have created a simple test example that produces the same message,
so I assume the issues will be related.

```
static void not_suitable_for_gather(unsigned char * __restrict__ pixels, int * __restrict__ indices, int indices_num)
{   
  for (int i = 0; i < indices_num; ++i)
  {
    int idx = indices[i] * 4;

    float r = pixels[idx + 0];
    float g = pixels[idx + 1];
    float b = pixels[idx + 2];
    float a = pixels[idx + 3] / 255.0f;

    pixels[idx + 0] = r;
    pixels[idx + 1] = g;
    pixels[idx + 2] = b;
    pixels[idx + 3] = a * 255.0f;
  }

  return;
}
```

Also, while creating my example, I came across a whole bunch of other messages,
that I am not really sure about their meaning or why would the particular construct
be problematic to vectorize, so is there any guide, book, tutorial, blog, whatever
that would explain these things to me ?

If that matters, I am using MingW 4.7 32-bit with QtCreator 2.7.0.

EDIT: The conclusion:

According to my tests and suggestions from this post, the message is most likely related to accessing data indirectly via an auxiliary index array, which leads to [gather/scatter addressing scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gather-scatter_%28vector_addressing%29) and at present `GCC` is not able (or does not want) to vectorize this. I was able to produce vectorized code with `clang++ 3.2-1` though.

Comment: I'd bet almost anything that it works just fine if you remove the `/255.0f` and `*255.0f` operations

Comment: Unfortunately not, I got the same message: `125: not vectorized: not suitable for gather D.32470_34 = *D.32469_33;`

Comment: This is debugging output from gcc, if at all it is documented there, but I would expect a need of deep understanding of the inner workings of gcc to interpret those; they are debug message at least.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I tried to google that message, but I wasn't very lucky, so I hoped someone here already faced this issue before and could help me out. One the few helpful things I found on this subject was [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/299392). Someone there says that `x86` lacks gather instruction (or something like that), so I suspect the culprit here is the `indices` array and the fact that I am indexing the `pixels` array indirectly ...

Comment: @jcxz: This thing is extremely specific to gcc, and likely to other options you specified in using it too. I would guess that only a minority of people here ever even heard of -ftree-vectorizer-verbose debugging option, let alone use it (successfully). You might be better of searching for answers in an area where the density of people actually working on gcc vectorizer code is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized version of your code would conceptually look like (using OpenCL syntax):

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices_num; ++i)
{
  int idx = indices[i] * 4;
  float4 factor = (1, 1, 1, 255.0f);

  char4 x1 = vload4(idx, pixels); // Line A
  float4 x2 = convert_float4(x1);
  float4 x3 = x2 / factor;
  float4 x4 = x3 * factor;
  char4 x5 = convert_char4(x4);
  vstore4(x5, idx, pixels); // Line B
}
```

But hold on; in line A you try to load four **chars** (aka uint8) from memory, and to store them on line B. That's not a common capability with x86; the only instruction sets I know of that support it are AVX2-enabled (Intel Haswells and later) and Xeon Phi's. Unless you're compiling to one of those, that could explain why your compiler rejects this vectorization opportunity.

The compiler can of course individually load 4 uint8s, build a vector from them, do the required vector operations, and manually store 4 values back; but I'm guessing that without gathers and scatters, individually loading and storing the values was probably deemed too expensive compared with the amount of actual work you save by vectorizing.

Comment: OK, so you say, that if I had a ton of other code, between the load and store, that compiler would bite through the indirect addressing ?
I will try to add some multiplications, divisions, ... to my test example and post the results.

Comment: So, I have added various multiplications, bit operations, subtractions, divisions, ... but compiler still choked on the line with `int idx = indices[i] * 4;`.

Comment: So, intrinsics similar to vload4() and convert_char4() would still need the alignment. You can check for each iteration, and only qualified elements could be streamed, others slow. This leads to custom vectorization instead of auto. If you are lucky, %80-%90 of the elements could be aligned and performance gain would be good.

Comment: @jcxz first of all, since a memory access can be orders of magnitude slower than arithmetic operations, "adding a few operations" might not help. Secondly, I don't actually know if your compiler has this sort of hueristic; I'm just saying, it's possible it did not vectorize because your data type is a single char and since there's no support in hardware for gathering it, it chose not to do anything.

Comment: @Oak I think you are perfectly right. Now I tried to compile my sample with `clang`, which did vectorize it. So the conclusion for me is to either forget about vectorization with `GCC`, do it by hand or try to reorganize my algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code which has vectors to multpily(and divide) your to-be-vectorized variables.:

```
static void not_suitable_for_gather(unsigned char * __restrict__ pixels, int * __restrict__ indices, int indices_num)
{   
  float dividerV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f};
  float multiplierV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f}; //choose anything that suits
  //Can use same vector to both multiply and divide if you want. But having different vectors can give some more pipelining(also needs more mem acccess so pick carefully)

  for (int i = 0; i < indices_num; ++i)
  {
    int idx = indices[i] * 4;

    float r = pixels[idx + 0]/dividerV[0];
    float g = pixels[idx + 1]/dividerV[1];
    float b = pixels[idx + 2]/dividerV[2];
    float a = pixels[idx + 3]/dividerV[3];

    pixels[idx + 0] = r*multiplierV[0];
    pixels[idx + 1] = g*multiplierV[1];
    pixels[idx + 2] = b*multiplierV[2];
    pixels[idx + 3] = a*multiplierV[3];
  }

  return;
}
```

Maybe this is easier to vectorize.

Aginst unknown loop bounds, try giving a direct constant instead of indices_num. This compiler is not just-in-time(maybe is but I did not heard of other than java) so, giving a compile-time-known constant could work maybe.

Here:

```
static void not_suitable_for_gather(unsigned char * __restrict__ pixels, int * __restrict__ indices)
{   
  float dividerV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f};
  float multiplierV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f}; //choose anything that suits
  //Can use same vector to both multiply and divide if you want. But having different vectors can give some more pipelining(also needs more mem acccess so pick carefully)

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    int idx = indices[i] * 4;

    float r = pixels[idx + 0]/dividerV[0];
    float g = pixels[idx + 1]/dividerV[1];
    float b = pixels[idx + 2]/dividerV[2];
    float a = pixels[idx + 3]/dividerV[3];

    pixels[idx + 0] = r*multiplierV[0];
    pixels[idx + 1] = g*multiplierV[1];
    pixels[idx + 2] = b*multiplierV[2];
    pixels[idx + 3] = a*multiplierV[3];
  }

  return;
}
```

Sometimes arrays are not aligned properly for vectorizing instructions. For example, cpu can increase the read/write performance only for 32B(or 16B)aligned arrays. Unaligned read/write is slower(or non-vectorizable)

Here:

```
static void not_suitable_for_gather(unsigned char * __restrict__ pixels, int * __restrict__ indices)
{   
     float dividerV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f};
     float multiplierV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f}; //choose anything that suits

     if(reinterpret_cast<size_t>pixels%32!=0)
     { 
      printf("array is not aligned! need to shift array or need to do serial calc. until aligned offset reached!");
      //do non-vectorized calc. When aligned offset reached, goto vectorizing code.
     }
     else
     {
       printf("array is aligned! Starting fast access.");
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
       {
           int idx = indices[i] * 4;

           float r = pixels[idx + 0]/dividerV[0];
           float g = pixels[idx + 1]/dividerV[1];
           float b = pixels[idx + 2]/dividerV[2];
           float a = pixels[idx + 3]/dividerV[3];

           pixels[idx + 0] = r*multiplierV[0];
           pixels[idx + 1] = g*multiplierV[1];
           pixels[idx + 2] = b*multiplierV[2];
           pixels[idx + 3] = a*multiplierV[3];
       }

       return;
   }
}
```

Maybe someone could open memcpy or some array-copying asm file and inject some multiplying code in it and compile as memcpy_with_multiplication(,,,) ?

My last suggestion: wrap r,g,b,a in a single array so they are in contiguous addresses.
Here:

```
static void not_suitable_for_gather(unsigned char * __restrict__ pixels, int * __restrict__ indices)
{   
  float dividerV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f};
  float multiplierV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f}; //choose anything that suits
  //Can use same vector to both multiply and divide if you want. But having different vectors can give some more pipelining(also needs more mem acccess so pick carefully)

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    int idx = indices[i] * 4;
    float rgba[4];

    rgba[0] = pixels[idx + 0]/dividerV[0];
    rgba[1] = pixels[idx + 1]/dividerV[1];
    rgba[2] = pixels[idx + 2]/dividerV[2];
    rgba[3] = pixels[idx + 3]/dividerV[3];

    pixels[idx + 0] = rgba[0]*multiplierV[0];
    pixels[idx + 1] = rgba[1]*multiplierV[1];
    pixels[idx + 2] = rgba[2]*multiplierV[2];
    pixels[idx + 3] = rgba[3]*multiplierV[3];
  }

  return;
}
```

"indices[i]" is not an explicit indice argument. This could be bad. Try some other way to show that to compiler. What happens when you put just i instead of indices[i] ? Does it compile same? indices[i] cannot be known at compile time or it is too complex for compiler.

Simpler(also wrong) and more vectorizable:

```
static void not_suitable_for_gather(unsigned char * __restrict__ pixels, int * __restrict__ indices)
{   
  float dividerV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f};
  float multiplierV[4]={1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,255.0f}; //choose anything that suits

  //you need to sorted version of indices[](or pixels[]) array to achieve something like this.
  for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i+=4) 
  {
    float rgba[4];

    rgba[0] = pixels[i + 0]/dividerV[0];
    rgba[1] = pixels[i + 1]/dividerV[1];
    rgba[2] = pixels[i + 2]/dividerV[2];
    rgba[3] = pixels[i + 3]/dividerV[3];

    pixels[i + 0] = rgba[0]*multiplierV[0];
    pixels[i + 1] = rgba[1]*multiplierV[1];
    pixels[i + 2] = rgba[2]*multiplierV[2];
    pixels[i + 3] = rgba[3]*multiplierV[3];
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code and compiled, but it is still not getting vectorized (the same message as before). Just to be sure I am not messing up somewhere else, here are the command line arguments passed to `MingW`: `-c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x -pedantic -O3 -msse2 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=6 -O2 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB` (copied from `Compile Output` window of `QtCreator`).

Comment: You may need aligned arrays too.

Comment: Checking the array alignment at runtime won't help, because the vectorization fails at compile time.

Comment: What if r,g,b,a are in contiguous addresses(in same array) ? Please look at last sample I tossed.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik give me a moment, I was off my computer for a little while now

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik so the unknown loop bound was not the culprit. Actually, when the loop bound is unknown, the message is: `not vectorized: number of iterations cannot be computed.`

Comment: Hmm. What about making r,g,b,a components together in an array of of 4 elements?

Comment: The array of four elements did not make any change either. What made the change was taking out the `indices` array and indexing `pixels` directly with `i`. So the most likely culprit seems to be indirect addressing, that I mentioned in comment under my question. However the problem for me is that this addressing scheme is quite important in my real code and I am not sure how to work around that ...

Comment: So a different indices[i] value for each element, meaning randomized-memory-access pattern? This could be bad. Maybe you can sort indices[i] array so you wont need indices[i] . Yes yes sort indices[i] array then use only the loop without indices[i].

Comment: Maybe you can sort pixels[i + 0] instead, so you dont need indices[]

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik can you elaborate more on what you mean with that sorting. The problem is that `pixels` is rather like a large sparse matrix of pixels and indices gives me the positions of pixels that need to be modified (`indices` is normally much smaller than `pixels`), so sorting `pixels` would in my opinion hurt performance despite the vectorized access and sorting `indices` would not solve much since the access to memory would still be in essence randomized.

Comment: @jcxz You are right, sorting is impossible for this situation. What happens when you compute on full-matrix? Maybe vectorization gives some 3x-4x performance, is the matrix very sparse? I mean, half of the elements are non-zero, then you can get some performance increasing by full-computing. If only %1 of matrix is non-zero then it is slow.